# Not able to call JQuery Popup from code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup, code-behind

I am new to Jquery. The problem I am facing is, I am able to call alertbox from code behind but when I replace alertbox with Jquery function, I am getting error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'loadPopupBox' is undefined"

This same function loadPopupBox() works perfectly fine when run at "document ready"

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

   function myFunction() {
        loadPopupBox();  //This doesn't work while calling from code behind
        //alert("Hi");   // This works fine with code behind
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {


        loadPopupBox();  //This works fine with document load

        function loadPopupBox() {    
            $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
            $("#container").css({ 
                "opacity": "0.3"
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

CODE BEHIND IS AS FOLLOWS

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "myFunction();", true);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards
Nikunj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop defining function inside the `$(document).ready`.
if you want to call a function on page load, define it outside the `$(document).ready` and then call it inside that.

Modify your code like this and it'll worked fine:

```
function myFunction() {
    loadPopupBox();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadPopupBox();
});

function loadPopupBox() {    
    $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
    $("#container").css({ 
        "opacity": "0.3"
    });
}
```